# Ubuntu 12.04 not booting after upgrade error drm:gen6_santiize_pm

Tags: 12.04, boot, drm

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP Envy laptop since a few years without any problems. I also regularly update Ubuntu. Yesterday (on 20.3.2014) when I updated, it stopped booting. I get the login screen but after logging in then unity does not load. If I open the command prompt using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I get the following error:

```
[   33.650398] [drm:gen6_sanitize_pm] *ERROR* Power management discrepancy: GEN6_RP_INTERRUPT_LIMITS expected 15070000, was 15000000
```

Can anybody please help me

Kiran

Comment: when we tried to reconfigure the graphics drivers

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which Kernel you are using. I had the same problem with 3.2.0-58-generic #88 and I recently updated it to 3.2.0-61 (the latest one available from the update manager) but since this problem appears when I didn't reboot since long time I am not sure if this solved the problem (I guess it didn't)

I have found that in principle 3.3.6 fixed this problem but I am not sure how to do it with Ubuntu 12.04 or if it is safe. Have a look here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+bug/1168467

Comment: Thank you very much for caring to respond. I tried many procedures mentioned in the forums but nothing worked for me. I wanted my laptop to be up soon for my work. So I reinstalled ubuntu 12.04 and its perfect now.